# selecting a value from a column based on value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a not too large DF. I want to add a column that looks up the value in the column of that specific row. So in the example below, the value should come from the column names 'PA1.13'

[image: example]

```
example = {'Honda Civic': [1],
        'Toyota': [0],
        'valuetolookup': ['Honda Civic'],
        'Result should be': [1]
        }
```

As you can see the column has two levels. I cannot seem to find how to make a second column level from scratch, but here I hope that I can work it out if someone wants to use my example code to solve it :-)

Comment: I can't follow your problem at all, please restate your question. Also, it's helpful if you can add the current and expected situation, preferably all in copy-able code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple apply() to extract data like you want:

```
import pandas as pd

example = {'Honda Civic': [1,3],
        'Toyota': [0,2],
        'valuetolookup': ['Honda Civic','Toyota'],
        'Result should be': [1,2]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(example)


#In the pandas apply, i use the "valuetolookup" column value to get the column name 
df["Result"] = df.apply(lambda x : x[x["valuetolookup"]],axis=1)
```

I added another row to show you that you can use different columns to lookup :)